# Symfony2 - Error when trying to use container:debug in console

Tags: symfony, containers

I have no idea what this error means can anyone tell me how to address this error when trying to use container:debug in the console?

Not sure if this helps, but I am using SonataAdminBundle, but oddly on the other projects I am using SonataAdminBundle this error does not occur.

I have tried clearing cache and removing cache `rm -rf app/cache/*` but this didn't do anything to address the problem.

**Error from using container:debug in console:**

```
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException]   
Unable to parse file "/var/www/html/Symfony/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugPr  
ojectContainer.xml".                                                         

[InvalidArgumentException]                                                 
[ERROR 94] Validation failed: no DTD found ! (in n/a - line 2, column 46)  
[ERROR 9] PCDATA invalid Char value 27 (in n/a - line 47, column 44)       
[ERROR 9] PCDATA invalid Char value 29 (in n/a - line 47, column 45)       
[ERROR 9] PCDATA invalid Char value 27 (in n/a - line 105, column 44)      
[ERROR 9] PCDATA invalid Char value 29 (in n/a - line 105, column 45)      
[ERROR 9] PCDATA invalid Char value 27 (in n/a - line 917, column 41)      
[ERROR 9] PCDATA invalid Char value 29 (in n/a - line 917, column 42)
```

Comment: Did you try doing `php app/console cache:clear --env=dev`? `cache:clear` and `rm -rf app/cache/*` are two very different things

Comment: Yes, I've tried this and the error still persists.

Comment: For anyone having this issue - in my case it were invalid characters in symfony's secret